# Stored procedure output parameter set back to POJO by iBATIS

Tags: java, orm, ibatis

I'm using iBATIS to call a Stored Procedure on MSSQL Server, the input parameters are properties on a POJO that is put to the map:

```
Map<String, Object> saveMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
saveMap.put("obj", myArticle);
update("save", saveMap);
```

All parameters are set correctly as input to the procedure so nothing wrong there. But one of the parameters is a output-parameter and and I was expecting it to be set back to the POJO but instead one extra mapping `"obj.new"=false` is put the map by iBATIS.
Here's a simplified version of the mapping showing the basic idea:

```
    <procedure id="save">
    {<include refid="Core.returned_value" />
    CALL SPRC_ARTICLE_NAME_SAVE (
        <include refid = "Core.common_fields" />
        @pArticle_id = #obj.art_id#
    ,   @pArtname = #obj.artname#
    ,   @pNewArticleName_flg = #obj.new,mode=INOUT#
    )}
</procedure>
```

After calling the procedure I have two mappings in Map passed to iBATIS:

- `"obj"=POJO`
- `"obj.new"=False`

Now I see that [iBatis documentation](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ibatis/java/ibatis-2/trunk/ibatis-2-docs/en/iBATIS-SqlMaps-2_en.pdf) saids *"When executing stored procedures – iBATIS will create objects for OUTPUT parameters"* so it makes sense. But my question is if there a way to instruct iBATIS put back the boolean value to the POJO after the procedure is called? I rather don't do the extra work of getting the value out of the map and set it to the POJO my self.

// Uhlén

Comment: I found Jeff Butler's answer to this Jeff Butler's answer to this http://groups.google.com/group/mybatis-user/browse_thread/thread/14826bc31c9f143d post to be very helpful when I faced a similar problem (although with a select statement rather than a update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using an explicit parameter map. See [Page 21 of the manual](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/pdf/iBATIS-SqlMaps-2_en.pdf)

Its rather verbose but its worked for me in the past.

```
<parameterMap id="swapParameters" class="map" >
    <parameter property="email1" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="INOUT"/>
    <parameter property="email2" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="INOUT"/>
</parameterMap>

<procedure id="swapEmailAddresses" parameterMap="swapParameters" >
    {call swap_email_address (?, ?)}
</procedure>
```